# JavaFX 8 DatePicker month-year-pane modify

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I have a Datepicker as shown here:
[DatePickerImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He6ce.png)

What I need is in the calendar popup.

There are 2 spinners, 1 for month and 1 for Year.

I want to obtain a DatePicker with 1 spinner showing month and year.
Example: [DatePicker Single Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkBxb.png)

There is a class DatepickerContent which contains a method createMonthYearPane() but I don't know if it is relevant.

Any help appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: See if these can help. These people created their own controls.  https://dzone.com/sites/all/files/DateChooser_styled.zip    and     https://bitbucket.org/sco0ter/extfx/src

Answer (score 0):

You need to change css, can be default CSS file called `modena.css`. In this stylesheet is applied for every JavaFX components.

You can find this file in the JavaFX jar file jfxrt.jar (should be located `/jdk1.8.x/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`). After unzipping that jar file you should find the `modena.css` under `com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/`

Find in the file a commented section DatePicker and you get all style properties that you are looking for.

Here is the [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)

Have a nice coding :)